# Finding the possible values Y can when dealing with r.v. transformations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let the continuous random variable $X$ have distribution function $F_X(x)$, and let $Y=F_X(X)$. That’s  right. You are transforming a random variable by its own cumulative distribution function.

a) For what values of y is $f_y(y) > 0$?

b) Find $f_Y(y)$.  Do you recognize this distribution?

I was able to solve parts a and b, and I noticed that $f_Y(y) = 1$ in part b, and is following the Normal distribution. However,
when finding the bounds of $y$, I noticed that since $Y=F_X(X)$, then using the rules of CDFs functions, we have that $0 \leq F_X(X) \leq 1$, and so $0 \leq Y\leq 1$. But, the solution at the back of the textbook claims that $0 < Y < 1$, which left me confused. How did they reach that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the [integral transform theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) you can see that $Y\sim U(0;1)$

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[F_X(x)\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X\leq F_X^{-1}(y)]=y$$

Comment: Thanks. I understand this part, but I am just unsure how my textbook solution key got that $0 < Y < 1$ and not $0 \leq Y \leq 1$?

Comment: @user62487108: there is no difference between $(0;1)$ and $[0;1]$ because $P(Y=0)=P(Y=1)=0$